# Spring Data JPA requires Eclipse link and Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've upgraded Spring data from 1.7.1 to 1.9.0 and instantly got dependency and compile errors:

> Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for
>   org.hibernate.ScrollableResults not found

For various reasons (both technical and political) we use Eclipse Link as our JPA provider. However it appears that the class `org.springframework.data.jpa.provider.PersistenceProvider` now contains static references to hibernate and open jpa classes.

```
import org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PersistenceCapable;
import org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OpenJPAPersistence;
import org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OpenJPAQuery;
import org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.FetchDirection;
import org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.JDBCFetchPlan;
import org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.LRSSizeAlgorithm;
import org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.ResultSetType;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaQuery;
import org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ScrollableCursor;
import org.hibernate.ScrollMode;
import org.hibernate.ScrollableResults;
import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateQuery;
```

I'm confused - I can't find any references to Hibernate being the exclusive JPA provider now. Is it the case we have to include hibernate and eclipse link (or bin eclipse link and rewrite large chunks of other code) in order to use 1.9?

Comment: Some more information.
Everything builds if I remove 

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>               <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>`

So it appears the EclipseLink JPA metamodel construction is not liking the extra classes imported with 1.8+ Spring data.
Is there a preffered way to generate the metamodel with maven?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not necessary. Those classes are only used at runtime, when you really use OpenJPA or Hibernate as persistence provide. Besides that, the usage of classes of all three providers already existed in version 1.7.1 in that class, so you would have had that problem earlier.

Did you change any compiler options at the same time as the version upgrade? I get this error sometimes, but for me it's only a warning, so if you have increased the error level for this type of compiler warnings, this might be the reason.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. The changes to this file were in the following commit:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/commit/5a3d92053293c8be4a405aa33ad8b413671a6f3a
That is tagged with branches for release 1.8 and above.
It isn't in any code for version 1.7.X

Comment: Why do you think that? I use Spring Data with Hibernate in many projects without any problems, and i don't have OpenJPA or Eclipselink in my classpathes. Regarding that file: In that commit additional imports were added, but there already were one or two imports per provider there in previous versions.

Comment: This is the file in the 1.7.x branch: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/1.7.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/PersistenceProvider.java
As you clearly can see, they already had those imports in that version.

Comment: The only reference in the whole Spring Data JPA source to hibernate scrollable results is in that class. 1.7.1 -> 1.7.4 work fine.
However 1.8 instantly complains of compile errors regarding a missing symbol for ScrollableResults. It's not a runtime error.

Comment: And no, no compiler options changed.

Comment: The 1.7.x branch did not contain all the imports including the one causing the error ScrollableResults